# Difference between MVC and Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to Asp.net.Please explain the difference betweeen MVC and Entity framework.

Comment: The two are completely different and have different purposes.

Comment: Title reads as this: 'Difference between YMCA and Banana float'.

Comment: To all you purists out there: I can understand his confusion. Most of the info about creating web applications that I have seen in the wild use both concepts making it sometimes difficult for noobs to recognize the separation. Perhaps the question could be worded better but the confusion is obvious IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MVC:**

MVC is one of three ASP.NET programming models.

MVC is a framework for building web applications using a MVC (Model View Controller) design:

- The Model represents the application core (for instance a list of
  database records).
- The View displays the data (the database records).
- The Controller handles the input (to the database records).
- The MVC model also provides full control over HTML, CSS, and
  JavaScript.
- MVC Design Pattern is given bellow-

[image]

**Entity Framework:**

Entity Framework (EF) is an object-relational mapper that enables .NET developers to work with relational data using domain-specific objects. It eliminates the need for most of the data-access code that developers usually need to write.

Ref.Link: [Entity Framework Introduction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), [MVC Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell, MVC builds web pages and EntityFramework abstracts database operations.

Answer (score 2):

**MVC**

> The Model-View-Controller (MVC) architectural pattern separates an
>   application into three main components: the model, the view, and the
>   controller. The ASP.NET MVC framework provides an alternative to the
>   ASP.NET Web Forms pattern for creating Web applications. 
>   [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx)

**Entity Framework**

> Entity Framework (EF) is an object-relational mapper that enables .NET
>   developers to work with relational data using domain-specific objects.
>   It eliminates the need for most of the data-access code that
>   developers usually need to write.
>   [more info](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework)

[ASP.NET MVC & the ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://www.codemag.com/article/1009071)

Answer (score 1):

These two are completely different so you can't derive a comparison between these two.

MVC is framework mainly concentrates on how you deliver a webpage from server to client.

Entity framework is an object relational mapper which helps you to abstract different types of databases (MSSQL,MySQL etc) and helps querying objects instead of having sql strings in our project.

Hope this helps!